# How to format app properly on an ipad from an iphone app in xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've written an app in Xcode and I set it for iPhone, but now I want to make the app available for iPad.  I don't want to go through the trouble of making it universal, is there a way I can run this iPhone app on my iPad correctly formatted?

Comment: iPhone apps run as-is on iPads. If you want your app to actually fully use the iPad screen, then you must make it a universal app and put in the extra work to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the target Device to iPad and run it. See below. Your UI may or may not look good depending on if you properly used either AutoLayout or Springs and Struts.

The iPad is a very different canvas for a UI than the iPhone and there is no definition of what "correctly formatted" really means when going from one to the other. It's a subjective matter and a computer is not going to decide if it looks good for you. As such, you may not get what you are looking for.

[image: Xcode Image]